# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que visual studio me muestre los formularios que estoy programando?

Tags: visual-studio

solo puedo ver el codigo y no la ventana de formularios

imagen de ejemplo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: F12 o Shift + F12, tambien puedes dar clic derecho y marcar dar clic en esa opcion

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!